# Regular expression in python 2.7 to identify any non numeric symbol in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am cleaning data in python. Some columns in a data frame should be numeric. But there are some rows in those columns that contains strings which could be a ?, / or any other non numeric symbols. I would like to make a boolean column which equals 1 if the value of selected columns are not numeric, 0 otherwise. I am new to python and I am not sure what is the regular expression for non  values.
And one thing I need to mention is since column c contains non numeric value, it's read as object ,not string or numeric. 
Sample input

```
      a     b   c   d
  1  10    20  30   40
  2  10/20 30   ?    50
```

This input is read as dataframe , called df.
Ideal output

```
      a     b   c   d    e
  1  10    20  30   40   0
  2  10/20 30   ?    50  1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample input, the desired output, and the code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: OK. But now colum `e` indicates that the *row* includes a non-numeric value in column `c`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. It could be any one of those columns. I just would like to see which row has the non numeric value so I could manually clean it.

Comment: do you have negative numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a pandas expert but you could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("in.csv", delimiter="\s+")

df['e'] = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).isdigit()).T.all().astype(int)
```

Input:

```
a  b  c  d
10 20 30 40
10/20 30 ? 50
3 4 5 6
```

Output:

```
       a   b   c   d  e
0     10  20  30  40  1
1  10/20  30   ?  50  0
2      3   4   5   6  1
```

If you did not have mixed types in the rows you could do:

```
df['e'] = df.applymap(np.isreal).T.all().astype(int)
```

Breaking it down:

```
 print(df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).isdigit()))
```

Outputs True or False for each row element based on whether it is a digit or not:

```
       a     b      c     d     e
0   True  True   True  True  True
1  False  True  False  True  True
2   True  True   True  True  True
```

Then we transpose with .T:

```
print(df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).isdigit()).T)
```

Getting:

```
      0      1     2
a  True  False  True
b  True   True  True
c  True  False  True
d  True   True  True
e  True   True  True
```

Then `.all` returns True if all elements are True for each row:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Lastly .astype(int) outputs:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Which we create the new col `e` with.

This will only work if you have positive digits.

Comment: i assume when you use x , it's just the name of a column ?

Comment: @YanSong, it  each each element in the rows, it casts to string and checks if it is a digit.

Comment: @YanSong,what do you want to do with the non numeric rows?

Comment: It depends on specific case. It's a data by manual input. So it's a bit tricky

Comment: well this will work on input like in your question, I don't think a regex would be any more useful

Comment: I think it's a great answer. I ll accept it when I verify with my data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the column is a `str`, not an `int`. You could use regex, but it would be faster and slightly easier to understand if you just use the `isdigit()` method for strings.

e.g:

```
>>> '1233456'.isdigit()
True
>>> '1234aaaa'.isdigit()
False
>>> '1234@'.isdigit()
False
>>> '123,456,789'.isdigit()
False
```

This method returns a boolean (True/False) which you can then insert into your desired column.

Comment: I am new to python. Correct me if I am wrong. I did not find isdigit() as a property of a column for a dataframe. I did df.a.isdigit() . it did not work

Comment: unless the numbers are negative then this won't work

Comment: @YanSong `isdigit()` is a property of a `string`, so if you can extract the `string` from the column of the dataframe (which I assume you need to do to use `regex`), you can use `isdigit()` on the extracted data

Comment: no . I don't have negative number. I am using ipython notebook. So I use tab after df.a. . I did not find isdigit() as one of its property.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I am assuming that there are only positive numbers, I would hope this would have been mentioned for the regex as well as it is important. Even if that were the case you can check for the '-' and subset it out of the string.

Comment: @YanSong You will have to apply it to each row of the column, unless you can access all the values of the column as a concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion given to me by a friend. We can debate which one is better.

```
    df2[df2.Year.str.contains("[^-0-9\/]+")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex for checking non digits.. you can use the following:

```
^[^0-9]+$
```

Which is equivalent to the following shorthand notation:

```
^\D+$
```

Code:

```
import re
matchObj = re.match( r'^\D+$', myStr)   //put your column
                                        // value in myStr
if matchObj:
   print "Match found!", matchObj.group()
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

Comment: I am learning python. can you write it out a more complete code

Comment: @karthik wouldn't it be better to use \D+ in to highlight the 10/20 case?

Comment: @karthikmanchala thanks. but it is not ideal. my ideal output is listed above.

Comment: @YanSong my answer is supposed to give an idea of how you can solve your problem... I am sure you can write your own logic using this..

Comment: @karthikmanchala It's not a good answer. That's all I am saying.